# Accessing the server's file system from a web application

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, web

What should I use as backend: Python or Server-Side-Javascript? I think Node.js allow the user to gain access to the file system, but I don't know if it's the best choice.

Edited: I just wanna do a kind of file manager using web technologies and learn in the meanwhile because I don't know nothing about web programming. If I use Python I'll learn about Django and if I use Node.js I'll learn Node, but I don't know which one is the best for that task.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems overly broad and cannot be really answered. You might want to ask a [more specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Really. You can do lots of stuff with either of them, and you didn't exactly give any hint on why one might be better. (The file system thingy is null, because python can access files as well.)

Comment: Java-**script** can not perform task **on** the server, it can mearly send requests to the server from the client.. It's still up to the server to perform the work, usually this is performed in form of Java, Python, PHP or some other server-side scripting language.

Comment: @Torxed I just wanted to mention you can indeed execute JS on the server.  If you haven't heard about this, I highly recommend you check out http://nodejs.org/.

Comment: It's not a server-side Java-script, it's a web client, parsing java-scripts which someone can (arguably) connect to, rendering it as a server application.. But it's like saying Java is a great language to develop GUI applications in.. It's not the intended use and just because someone had a bad child-hood and wanted to see if it was possible doesn't make it any good because it was possible :P
Stick to proper applications that doesn't involve latency, high-level nonsense if you're going to build scale-able things :P

Comment: @Torxed ... Node.js IS server side JavaScript, man.

Comment: @joeltine Again, just because something CAN be run on the server side, doesn't mean it should...
Node.js is a Web-engine parsing javascript so, it's basically Google Chrome or FireFox parsing javascript ON the server giving you a "server feeling".. still not something that should be implemented in a larger environment.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer here is, *whatever language you're most familiar with*.  All server-side language choices have some APIs for accessing the local filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that your question has enough information to provide a useful answer.  The ultimate choice is going to depend upon multiple factors such as:

- What the goal of the project is.
- What the constraints on the project are.
- Who will end up maintaining this code.

Also note that if you just want to serve files from some subset of the filesystem then you might be better off using a web server rather than essentially rolling your own.  The authors of that code have probably already dealt with any nasty security issues and corner cases that you're likely to overlook.

Comment: And not to mention the ugly overhead of the HTTP protocol to begin with for file-sharing >_O That's a big + for using pre-packaged libraries/software..

Answer (score 1):

Python as well as Node.js has API's to access the file system. They can perform operations such as reading a file, iterating through directories etc... For python you can take a look here http://docs.python.org/2/library/filesys.html and for nodejs http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system